# Replacing quotation marks in Word (reg ex)

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I have a large text document with inconsistent quotation marks, i.e.

> ...Dolore magna aliquam “lorem ipsum” dolor sit amet, 'consectetuer
>   adipiscing" elit, volutpat. Ut "wisi" enim...

and I want to convert every existing style of quotation only to one style, Guillemet style (» and «), so that example sentence should be like

> ...Dolore magna aliquam »lorem ipsum« dolor sit amet, »consectetuer
>   adipiscing« elit, volutpat. Ut »wisi« enim...

Is that that possible only with find/replace with wildcards? The closest regex I got is

```
[“'"](?=[a-zA-Z\,\.\s])([a-zA-Z\,\.\s]*)[”'"]
```

but it is not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any quotes within quotes, and should these be treated differently?

Comment: There are, but in that case even the nested quotes stay in `» «` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the preceding/following space to determine which "side" of the word the quote you want is on.

`\s` in regex matches a whitespace character (ie a space, or tab, etc.).

So, first search for `\s[“'"]` and replace with `<space>»`, then search for `[”'"]\s` and replace with `«<space>` (replace `<space>` with an actual space character :) ).

Comment: Simple and yet efficient, thanks! :) Although, MS Word doesn't seem to accept \s as a whitespace character (use wildcard is checked), but I'll go take a look on "Word for dummies" first :) But... is there a way to use regex in Word except through a find/replace screen (and VB macro, since I can't write in VB - I'm a novice in python and C#)?

Comment: And another newbie question; what about when a quotation mark is right before comma or a stop sign, i.e. ``"sample text", "second text".``?

Comment: Just group stops with the space, ie: `[”'"][\s,.]`.  If you can read and write C# you can read and write VB(A). ;)

Comment: For future readers, the equivalent to `\s` that I use in wildcards is `[ ^s^t]`: literal space, nonbreaking space (`^s`), and tab (`^t`).